# How to pass multi optional URL parameters in django?

Tags: python, django, django-2.2

How to pass multi optional URL parameters?

For example I want pass 2 params: `my_color` and `my_year`, but they are optional, so may be none of them will be passed, may be both, or may be only one.

Currently in `urls.py` I have :

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^products/(?P<my_color>.*)/(?P<my_year>.*)$', some_view),
]
```

This obviously is not correct and works only if both of them are passed.

What would be correct solution?

P.S.
I found answers when only one optional parameter needs to be pass, but not figured out how to do same for few parameters. Also it seems "multiple-routes option" is not solution in this case (?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `myyear` is a sequence of *digits*, and `mycolor` is a equence of *non-digits*, you can use

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^products/((?P<my_color>\D+)/)?(?P<my_year>\d+)$', some_view),
]
```

this will pass an *empty string* for the corresponding elements if the `my_color` or `my_year` are not present. You thus can write a view that looks like:

```
def some_view(request, my_color, my_year):
    if my_color:
        # …
    if my_year:
        # …
```

If both have the same sequence of characters, this is not *possible*, since how would you interpret `products/bla`? Is `bla` the color, or the year?

That being said, I think you make it too complicated. You can define four patterns, for example:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^products/', some_view),
    path(r'^products/<int:year>/'),
    path(r'^products/<str:color>/'),
    path(r'^products/<str:color>/<int:year>/', some_view),
]
```

Here you thus define four views for the same view. The view can then define optional parameter:

```
def some_view(request, color=None, year=None):
    # …
```

Comment: "If both have the same sequence of characters, this is not possible, since how would you interpret products/bla? Is bla the color, or the year?" this is exactly what I don't get. example is about 2 parameters, but what if we need to pass 10 optional params ?

Comment: @OtoShavadze: but your parameters are *optional*, imagine that you can both capture a `color` and a size, how will you interpret `/large`? Is `large` a `color` or a `size`?  Semantically of course it is a size, but it will be hard to write a regex that only captures colors. The optional part results in ambiguity.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, but how to solve   cases like this  then? May be just pass params using standart way `/?my_color=a&my_year=b` is only one way ?

Comment: @OtoShavadze: I think for a large amount of optional parameters, that is the preferred way, since then it is clear what the parameter is. Furthermore it is more convenient, since Django will already wrap this in a dictionary-like object.